# Run MySQL on different port with different config

Tags: mysql, database, docker, config

I'm trying to run another instance of MySQL on separate port with different config.

#### Attempt 1

`docker run --name dbname -v /home/custom-mysql-configs/dbname-config-folder:/etc/mysql  -p 0.0.0.0:3312:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysupersecretpassword -d mysql:5.5`

When I run `SHOW VARIABLES;` in `mysql -u root -p --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3312` I get the same variables as `mysql -u root -p --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306` that are set in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

#### Attempt 2

`docker run --name dbname -v /home/custom-mysql-configs/dbname-config-folder:/etc/mysql/conf.d  -p 0.0.0.0:3312:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysupersecretpassword -d mysql:5.5`

Then when I ran

`mysql -u root -p --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306`

I got the following error:

> ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading
>   initial communication packet', system error: 0

What am I doing wrong and how should I run the new MySQL instance?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your new container with:

`$ docker run --name dbname -v /home/custom-mysql-configs/dbname-config-folder:/etc/mysql/conf.d  -p 0.0.0.0:3312:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysupersecretpassword -d mysql:5.5`

You should be connecting to it through:

`$ mysql -u root -p --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3312`

Your command was connecting to your original container, on port 3306.

I'd also suggest showing some of your MySQL conf.d files, as it might help further.